# Checking if a pointer in NULL

Tags: zig

Is there a nicer way of achieving the same result as the following code in a nicer way?

```js
if (window == @intToPtr(?*c.GLFWwindow, 0))
```

I want to check if a pointer to any kind of object (in this case, a nullable [of course] pointer to a GLFWwindow) is NULL. Is there a better way of doing this so that I don't have to write `@intToPtr(?*T, 0))` every time I need a NULL pointer (of course a very common occurrence when interfacing with C libraries)

I tried searching for a solution for a while but found nothing. Maybe if there isn't a way to do this specific thing in zig, perhaps there's a way to define a C-like macro `GLFWwindowNULL` to `@intToPtr(?*c.GLFWwindow, 0))`?

Comment: Sorry, I posted this and immediately found the answer. I have answered the question now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `null` keyword can be used in this situation:

```js
if (window == null)
```